# Trouble with POPUP and Events in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a button that activate a service but before that service is activate i need to force the user to enter a text, for that task i create a user control that allow the user to enter text and validate it, on that control i have 2 buttons OK and cancel, OK button is working fine but the cancel is supposed to hide the popup, but the event don't get triggered, i need to hit the button several times before that happen, i am also getting a similar problem if the person hits back i cant get rid of the popup without closing the app. What is the best approach to work with popup and in this case why is the event is not getting trigger on the first hit

public partial class TicketView
{
       Controls.TextInputBox textInputControl;

```
    private void InitCloseTxtInput()
    {
        textInputControl = new Controls.TextInputBox(8, 0);
        textInputControl.CancelBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CancelBtn_Click);
        textInputControlForCamara.CancelBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CancelBtn_Click);
    }
    private void AppBarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitCloseTxtInput();
        PivotContainer.IsEnabled = false;
        this.popup = new Popup();
        this.popup.Margin = new Thickness(0, 150, 0, 0);
        this.popup.Child = textInputControl;
        this.popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    void OkBtnOnPopUP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Call Service
    }
    void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.popup.IsOpen = false;
        this.PivotContainer.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

}

If anyone have any out of question recommendation for this piece of code, Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line was the problem don’t exactly know why but when trying to re do de control i comment this line and all start to work just fine

this.popup.Margin = new Thickness(0, 150, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

At least in the code, it does not seem like you are hooking `CancelBtnPopUP_Click` anywhere.

Is that the entirety of the code?

Comment: Copy Paste mistake CancelBtnPopUP_Click is CancelBtn_Click

I solve the problem adding a diferent event for each cancelBtn... but i dont understand why is that a problem

Comment: Not really sure what you mean - if you dont hook that event, your code will not be called (CancelBtn_Click)

Comment: Hmm. Okay. I am not sure what's going on then. Can you do me a favor? Put a breakpoint on this.popup = new Popup(); and right-click this.popup and choose "Make Object ID". Then, break on this.popup.IsOpen = false; and inspect this.popup and tell me if it says "#1" at the beginning/end?